# Convert list of nested dictionary into dictionary in Python

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list of nested dictionary as below. There is list inside the dictionary as well. I don't want to change the inner list but to turn the entire list into dictionary. The list is as below:

```
[{"id" : "A", "data" : [{"key_1" : 012},{"key_2" : 123}, {"key_3" : 234}]}]
```

I only want to change the list itself to dictionary without changing the inner list as below:

```
{{"id" : "A", "data" : [{"key_1" : 012},{"key_2" : 123}, {"key_3" : 234}]}}
```

Appreciate your help in this.

Comment: The expected result isn't valid.

Comment: ggorlen is correct, you need to have a key: value pair in a dictionary. The closest that to what I think what you want is (the top list is called 'a'): new_dict={'keyname':a[0]}

Comment: Thanks @jhso. I amended the list to show the hierarchy. Initially the list `a` is `[{'Emp_id': 'A', 'Gender': 'M', 'Age': 32, 'Result': [{'Month': 'Aug', 'Incentive': 3000}, {'Month': 'Sep', 'Incentive': 3500}, {'Month': 'Oct', 'Incentive': 2000}]}, {'Emp_id': 'B', 'Gender': 'M', 'Age': 35, 'Result': [{'Month': 'Aug', 'Incentive': 1500}]}, {'Emp_id': 'C', 'Gender': 'F', 'Age': 31, 'Result': [{'Month': 'Aug', 'Incentive': 5000}, {'Month': 'Sep', 'Incentive': 2400}]}]`. By applying `new_dict={'keyname':a[0]}`, the new_dict keeps only `"Emp_id" : "A"`. How can I keep all?

Comment: You should format the input and expected output such that the structure is clear.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know you had multiple dicts in the list. You can either do new_dict={'keyname':a}, or do a dict comprehension, ie. new_dict={i['Emp_id']:i for i in a}

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary comprehension and `zip` the list of dictionaries up with whatever list of keys you want. Here is an example using a subset of ascii lowercase letters:

```py
{ pair[0]: pair[1] for pair in list(zip([*string.ascii_lowercase[0:len(input)]], input))}
```

```py
>>> foo = [   {   'Age': 32,
        'Emp_id': 'A',
        'Gender': 'M',
        'Result': [   {'Incentive': 3000, 'Month': 'Aug'},
                      {'Incentive': 3500, 'Month': 'Sep'},
                      {'Incentive': 2000, 'Month': 'Oct'}]},
    {   'Age': 35,
        'Emp_id': 'B',
        'Gender': 'M',
        'Result': [{'Incentive': 1500, 'Month': 'Aug'}]},
    {   'Age': 31,
        'Emp_id': 'C',
        'Gender': 'F',
        'Result': [   {'Incentive': 5000, 'Month': 'Aug'},
                      {'Incentive': 2400, 'Month': 'Sep'}]}]


>>> { pair[0]: pair[1] for pair in list(zip([*string.ascii_lowercase[0:len(input)]], input))}


>>> {   'a': {   'Age': 32,
             'Emp_id': 'A',
             'Gender': 'M',
             'Result': [   {'Incentive': 3000, 'Month': 'Aug'},
                           {'Incentive': 3500, 'Month': 'Sep'},
                           {'Incentive': 2000, 'Month': 'Oct'}]},
    'b': {   'Age': 35,
             'Emp_id': 'B',
             'Gender': 'M',
             'Result': [{'Incentive': 1500, 'Month': 'Aug'}]},
    'c': {   'Age': 31,
             'Emp_id': 'C',
             'Gender': 'F',
             'Result': [   {'Incentive': 5000, 'Month': 'Aug'},
                           {'Incentive': 2400, 'Month': 'Sep'}]}}
```

note: you can pretty print code as follows:

```
import pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
pp.pprint(data)
```